# How to get Ant sshexec working with non-empty passphrase

Tags: java, ant, ssh

How to use the `sshexec` task of Ant with a private key that is configured with a passphrase?

I found the following workarounds:

- Remove the passphrase from the private key (most practical)
- Pass the passphrase as a command line option for example `-Dpass=mypass` (insecure)
- Hardcode the passphrase in the Ant job definition file (worst)

None of these is a good option for me, but the first is acceptable.

Having the private key loaded in `pageant` doesn't seem to help at all. From other answers it seems as if Ant is trying to access it, but it cannot, falling back to password authentication, which fails with:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:490)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:162)
... (rest of the stack trace omitted)
```

Another common symptom is when the Unlimited Strength JCE is not installed, the error is something like:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: The cipher 'aes256-cbc' is required, but it is not available.
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.loadPPK(KeyPair.java:942)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:515)
... (rest of the stack trace omitted)
```

To return to my question, how to make this work properly? Using private key with passphrase, without hardcoding it anywhere or entering on the command line? It would be best to make use of `pageant`, where I can enter my passphrase and store the private key before running the Ant task.

Comment: Have you found solution?  I am using "Remove the passphrase from the private key" at the moment but I am looking for solution if scp/sshexec may work with `pageant`.

Comment: @ChauCheeYang nope, haven't found. As soon as I do, I'd post it here. It's not really a burning issue right now.

Answer (score 2):

If you run your ant-file from the commandline you may have it ask for your passphrase instead of hardcoding it. The important part is prompting for the passphrase, storing it in a property and referencing this property in the passphrase-argument.

```
  <target name="copy">    
    <input message="Enter passphrase for keyfile:" addproperty="the.password">
        <handler classname="org.apache.tools.ant.input.SecureInputHandler" />
    </input>
    <upload-files host="the.host" />
  </target>

  <macrodef name="upload-files">
    <attribute name="host" />
    <sequential>
      <scp file="${the.file}"
           todir="@{host}:directoryname/${filename}"
           keyfile="${key.file}" passphrase="${the.password}" verbose="true"/>      
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>
```

Requirements:

- Ant 1.7.1
- Java 6, if it is run on Java 5 it will fallback to a "normal"
- running the ant-file from commandline (according to the source eclipse does not handle the SecureInputHandler)

Source: http://www.dcepler.net/post.cfm/hiding-password-input-in-ant